# Problemas com função ao tentar realizar deleção

Tags: php, jquery, json

Estou com um problema ao efetuar a tentativa de deleção e recebo uma mensagem de erro no console, meu script está assim:

```
<form action="" id="frmDeleta" class="smart-form"> 
  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-danger"> Excluir </button>
  <input name="IdEvento" type="hidden" value="<?php echo $IdEvento; ?>">
</form>
```

```
    $(document).ready(function () {             

            $("#frmDeleta")({               
                // NÃO ALTERAR O CÓDIGO 
                errorPlacement: function (error, element) {
                    error.insertAfter(element.parent());
                },
                submitHandler: function (form) {
                    var data = $(form).serialize();                 
                    // console.log(data);                   
                    $.ajax({
                        type: 'POST',
                        url: 'pDeletaAgendamento.php',
                        data: data,
                        dataType: 'json',
                        beforeSend: function () {
                            $("#msgResult").html('×AVISO! Enviando...');
                        },
                        success: function (response) {
                            if (response.codigo == "1") {
                                $("#msgResult").html('×AVISO!' + response.mensagem + '');
                                // RESETANDO O FORMULÁRIO APÓS GRAVAÇÃO
                                $('#frmDeleta').each(function () {
                                    this.reset();   
                                });

                            } else {
                                $("#msgResult").html('×ATENÇÃO! ' + response.mensagem + '');
                            }
                        },
                        error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
                            // console.warn(xhr.responseText);
                            console.log(xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError);
                            $("#msgResult").html('×ATENÇÃO! Ocorreu um erro ao tentar enviar o Agendamento. Contate o departamento de TI.');
                        }
                    });
                    return false;
                }

            });

    });
```

Mas no meu console estou recebendo a seguinte mensagem:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Conferiu se o jquery está iniciado corretamente? Pelo erro está dizendo que `$(...)` não é uma função.

Comment: Você precisa adicionar o `jQuery` antes de executar o `ajax`

Comment: `#frmDeleta` se refere ao `name` do objeto `form`, não ao `id`

Comment: Estou iniciando corretamente o JQuery @ErlonCharles e Kenny Rafael

Comment: Realmente não tinha reparado neste trecho: `$("#frmDeleta")({`, precisa adicionar algum método como o `$("#frmDeleta").submit({` por exemplo, não que isso mereça uma resposta, pequeno erro de sintaxe, porém a questão é que terá outros erros no seu script, vai atualizando ai.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Dois erros visíveis no seu código,

1° a tag `#frmDeleta` se refere a um `name` de formulário, não a um `id`

2° Acredito que você quis utilizar a função `submit` usando o `jquery`, que eu saiba não existe uma chamada do tipo `$("#frmDeleta")({` <strike>(me corrijam se eu estiver errado)</strike>

---

Na verdade creio que você está tentando utilizar o plugin [validate](https://jqueryvalidation.org/), a sintaxe correta seria:  `$("#frmDeleta").validate({`

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#frmDeleta").validate({
    // NÃO ALTERAR O CÓDIGO 
    errorPlacement: function(error, element) {
      error.insertAfter(element.parent());
    },
    submitHandler: function(form) {
      var data = $(form).serialize();
      // console.log(data);                   
      $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'pDeletaAgendamento.php',
        data: data,
        dataType: 'json',
        beforeSend: function() {
          $("#msgResult").html('×AVISO! Enviando...');
        },
        success: function(response) {
          if (response.codigo == "1") {
            $("#msgResult").html('×AVISO!' + response.mensagem + '');
            // RESETANDO O FORMULÁRIO APÓS GRAVAÇÃO
            $('#frmDeleta').each(function() {
              this.reset();
            });
          } else {
            $("#msgResult").html('×ATENÇÃO! ' + response.mensagem + '');
          }
        },
        error: function(xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
          // console.warn(xhr.responseText);
          console.log(xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError);
          $("#msgResult").html('×ATENÇÃO! Ocorreu um erro ao tentar enviar o Agendamento. Contate o departamento de TI.');
        }
      });
      return false;
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.11.1/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>

<form action="" id="frmDeleta" name="frmDeleta" class="smart-form">
  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-danger">Excluir</button>
  <input name="IdEvento" type="hidden" value="<?php echo $IdEvento; ?>">
</form>
```

Comment: Olá @Marcelo Bonifazio, obrigado pela ajuda, mas não estou querendo usar o validate, simplesmente quero enviar o ID para a página de deleção e receber um retorno de erro ou acerto.